# Scale image using jQuery Slider not positioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, scale

I have created a slider to manipulate an image within the DOM. What I would like to happen is for the image to scale but stay centered as it is being scaled. The problem I have is I am giving the user the ability to position the image using .draggable but after they have moved the image and they try to scale it again it jumps position. I have added a fiddle to the Question to show what I mean.

Basically if you use the slider to change the size of the image before you drag it the image will scale and position correctly, however if you move the image after you have first scaled and then try and scale again after dragging the image jumps on the first iteration of the slider then scales and positions correctly.

The strange thing is if you scale the image drag it scale it back down to the original size drag again and then try and scale it positions correctly. It looks like it has something to do with the previous slider value.

Code for slider and drag:

```
$( "#slide1" ).slider({
            range: "min",
            min: -70,
            max: 150,
            step: 10,
            value: 0,


   slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var zv = (1+ ui.value/100); // Rotate Value
        var nx = 0;
        var ny = 0;
        nzo = calculateAspectRatioFit(iwz, ihz, iwz*(zv), ihz*(zv));
        $('#img1').width(nzo.width).height(nzo.height);
        var wd = Math.abs(iwz - nzo.width);
        var hd = Math.abs(ihz - nzo.height);


        if (zv < 1){
            nx = (ixz+(wd/2));
            ny = (iyz+(hd/2));
            $('#img1').css({'left':nx+'px','top':ny+'px'});
        } else {
            nx = (ixz-(wd/2));
            ny = (iyz-(hd/2));
            $('#img1').css({'left':nx+'px','top':ny+'px'});
        }
    }
});



$('#img1').draggable({
            drag:function(event, ui){
                var il = ui.position.left;
                var it = ui.position.top;
                var iw = $(this).width();
                var ih = $(this).height();
                $('#img1').css({'top':it+'px','left':il+'px'});
            },
            stop:function(){
                ixz = $('#img1').position().left;
                iyz = $('#img1').position().top;
            }
        });

});
```

All the code is within the [JSFiddle found here](http://jsfiddle.net/Boldonglen/af0zvxg2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out how to do this. What i had to do was check to see if it had been dragged and if it was dragged on the first iteration of the zoom i needed to take away the initial zoom value width and height difference from the x and y position before i manipulated the image. Hard to explain but here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Boldonglen/af0zvxg2/7/)

```
if (dragged && zc == 0){
        var wt = Math.abs(iwz - nzo.width);
        var ht = Math.abs(ihz - nzo.height);
        if (czv < 1){
            ixz = ixz-(wt/2);
            iyz = iyz-(ht/2);
        } else {
            ixz = ixz+(wt/2);
            iyz = iyz+(ht/2);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while calculating nx and ny do not add or remove wd/hd. This will solve your problem

```
            if (zv < 1){
                nx = (ixz);
                ny = (iyz);
                $('#img1').css({'left':nx+'px','top':ny+'px'});
            } else {
                nx = (ixz);
                ny = (iyz);
                $('#img1').css({'left':nx+'px','top':ny+'px'});
            }
```

Comment: Yes this works to solve the zoom issue after dragging but if i remove these values it does not zoom in on the centre of the image. I need the image to be scaled so that it is centred.